# Read text file as a whole

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need your help. I want to read a text file "as a whole" and not line by line. This is because by doing line by line my regex doesn't work well, it needs the whole text. So far this is what I am being doing:

```
with open(r"AllText.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        for i in re.finditer(regexp_v3, line):
            print i.group()
```

I need to open my file, read it all, search if for my regex and print my results. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that use `read`:

```
with open("AllText.txt") as fp:
    whole_file_text = fp.read()
```

Note however, that your test will contain `\n` where the new-line used to be in your text.

For example, if this was your text file:

```
#AllText.txt
Hello
How
Are
You
```

Your `whole_file_text` string will be as follows:

```
>>> whole_file_text
'Hello\nHow\nAre\nYou'
```

You can do either of the following:

```
>>> whole_file_text.replace('\n', ' ')
'Hello How Are You'

>>> whole_file_text.replace('\n', '')
'HelloHowAreYou'
```

Comment: You are my hero. You answered even the question that I was gonna ask (regarding new lines). Thank you so much! I'll promote your answer once it passes enough time (4 minutes according to the website)

Comment: Sorry, forgot it. Done now. :)

Answer (score 5):

To get all the content of a file, just use [`file.read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

```
all_text = fp.read()  # Within your with statement.
```

`all_text` is now a single string containing the data in the file.

---

Note that this *will* contain newline characters, but if you are extracting things with a regex they shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Nice answer, but sshashank124 also provided a solution for newlines :)

Comment: @Con7e Be careful with getting rid of newlines. It will make all of the lines indistinguishable and make it harder to work with. I would just leave them in.

Comment: @Con7e Also if my answer was helpful to you, consider accepting it by clicking the tick below the vote counts so that it turns green and stays green. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to read the entire file into memery, you can use `mmap`

> Memory-mapped file objects behave like both strings and like file objects.

```
import re, mmap

with open(r'AllText.txt', 'r+') as f:
    data = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    mo = re.finditer(regexp_v3, data)
```

Comment: +1 I love it. Does it work on Windows as well?

Comment: @mskimm Yeah, But note you cannot create an empty mapping on Windows, see more on [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/mmap.html) :-)

Comment: This seems unnecessary, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23132390/432913) answer is much simpler.